# Using Hive along with Spark Cassandra connector?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Can I use Hive in concert with the Spark cassandra connector ?

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
scala> hiveCtx = new HiveContext(sc)
```

This produces:

```
ivysettings.xml file not found in HIVE_HOME or HIVE_CONF_DIR,    
/etc/hive/conf.dist/ivysettings.xml will be used
```

and then

```
 scala> val rows = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT first_name,last_name,house FROM 
           test_gce.students WHERE student_id=1")
```

results in this error:

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table test_gce.students; line 1 pos 48
   at    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:260)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:268)
```

...

Is it possible to create a HiveContext from the SparkContext and use it as I am trying to do while using the Spark cassandra connector ?

Here is how I called spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --jars ~/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.4.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.240.0.0
```

Also, I am able to successfully access Cassandra with the pure connector code rather than just using Hive:

```
scala> val cRDD=sc.cassandraTable("test_gce", "students")
    scala>cRDD.select("first_name","last_name","house").where("student_id=?",1).collect()
res0: Array[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] =     
Array(CassandraRow{first_name: Harry, last_name: Potter, house: Godric Gryffindor})
```

Comment: Exception says "no such table test_gce.students". Does the table exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am able to access it successfully using just the pure connector by itself. I am wondering if I can use the hiveContext to do so as well.

Comment: Are you using the same "hive-default.xml" and is it there in SPARK_HOME/conf directory? Also you can try passing hive-default with --files option. Yes you can use HIveContext, provided hive-default.xml is  used by your connector. generally this error occurs when your connector is using a different metastore URL.